# More than 14 decimal places in settings

Tags: formatting

In the default settings of Mathematica, it is possible to work with 14 decimal places: Edit - Preferences - Appearance - Numbers - Formatting, in Samples hear it's 14-digit decimal only. Can I increase this number, for example to 25?

Answer (score 1):

There is no global setting for precision. What you reference only affects how numbers are shown on the screen, not how they are represented, or how many significant digits they hold.

Instead of a global setting, each individual number has a precision associated with it. `1.0` has *machine precision*, meaning approximately 15 decimal digits of precision and no precision tracking. `` 1.0`30 `` would have 30 digits of precision and supports precision tracking.

Read more here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html

Comment: I would like to save about 25 decimal places in a file, but when I write it like this: PutAppend[ " x= ", N[x,25], " y= ", N[y,25], "D:/Users/.../file.txt"]],
only 14-16 decimal places are still written in the file. Could you please explain why?

Comment: @MamMam Please read the tutorial I posted from "Exact and Approximate Results" up to "Machine‐Precision Numbers", as these issues can only be discussed if you are familiar with the concepts presented in these parts of the tutorial. In short, if `y` does not have 25 digits of precision, then there is nothing to export. Is your `y` exact or inexact? If inexact, did you check its precision?

Comment: @MamMam Perhaps `PutAppend[" x= ", 
 ToString@NumberForm@N[Rationalize[Sqrt[3.], 0], 25], "/tmp/file.txt"]`, although, as Szabolcs implies, the last nine or ten digits are unreliable. Compare `N[Rationalize[Sqrt[3.], 0], 25]` and
`N[Sqrt[3], 25]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But the number one gets this way is quite literally no closer to $\sqrt{3}$ than making up the last 9-10 digits arbitrarily, or just using zeros for those digits (i.e. sticking with the 15 digits that machine precision has). If OP wants more than machine precision, then `y` needs to be computed with more than machine precision.

Comment: I guess that was my point, for which I think the example was evidence. (BTW, I think it takes 17 digits to unambiguously specify the 53 bits of the mantissa in some cases.)